# How to get value from td's via $_POST

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get `<td>` values from a table:

```
<table id="MyTable" class="table">
    <tbody name="MyTable" id="tbody">
        <tr name="MyTable">
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%">value 1</td>
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%">value 2</td>
            <td name="MyTable" id="td"><input type="button" class="form-control" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

I want to know if it's possible by using `$_POST` to get those values

Comment: Use PHPs [`DOMDocument`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/class.domxpath.php) to travers the HTML table and extract the values you want.

Comment: With the code fragment above it is very unlikely to do anything at all. It's just static. Are you posting this html to the backend? Or something else?

Comment: am surrounding this by a `<form>` to another page and try to get the value by `$_POST['MyTable']`

Comment: The `name` attribute in `tbody`, `tr` and `td` is not a valid attribute. Consider to remove it. However as HTML5, custom attribute names are valid.

Comment: You require a form to send POST values to the server. You cannot use a table as a form, but you can stick form elements in the table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="to_something.php" method="post">
<table id="MyTable" class="table">
    <tbody name="MyTable" id="tbody">
        <tr name="MyTable">
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%"><input type="hidden" name="td_1" value="value_1">value 1</td>
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%"><input type="hidden" name="td_2" value="value_2">value 2</td>
            <td name="MyTable" id="td"><input type="button" class="form-control" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**to_something.php**

```
<?php

    $td1 = $_POST['td_1'];
    $td2 = $_POST['td_2'];
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the values you are referring to using the `$_POST` you need to do two things:

- Wrap your code fragment inside a `form` element
- Use `input` tags inside the `td`(s) where the attribute **value** of each input should be the value that you want obtain later.

Also you need to post that form back to server.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<table id="MyTable" class="table">
    <tbody name="MyTable" id="tbody">
        <tr name="MyTable">
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%"><input type="text" name="v1" value="value 1"></td>
            <td name="MyTable" width="35%"><input type="text" name="v2" value="value 2"></td>
            <td name="MyTable" id="td"><input type="button" class="form-control" value="Edit"></td>
        </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

now you can use the variables `$_POST['v1']` and `$_POST['v2']` to get it.