# Passing Form Data to separate PHP Page

Tags: php, forms, post, html-table

I have a table with multiple columns (index.php). One column is a checkbox. Whenever the checkbox is checked, it displays another row where you can select a quantity. You can then hit a button called "Add to Order" and it will take you to a confirmation page (index-order.php) where I want it to display each row along with all of the data in that specified row that has the checkbox checked. Currently, I am getting no errors in my console, but no data is being displayed at all.

What do I need to change to make this happen? Here is what I have so far.

Index.php code:

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="index-order.php"> 

<section id="addToOrder">   
<button type="submit" class="order" id="order" name="order" value="AddToOrder">Add to Order</button>
</section>

<br>


<div id="my-div2" class="ui-widget">
<div class="ui-widget">

<table id="merchTable" cellspacing="5" class="sortable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="ui-widget-header">
            <th class="sorttable_nosort"></th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Loc</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Report Code</th>
            <th class="merchRow">SKU</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Special ID</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Description</th>
            <th class="merchRow">Quantity</th>
            <th class="sorttable_nosort">Unit</th>
            <th style="display: none;" class="num">Quantity #</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <?php foreach ($dbh->query($query) as $row) {?>

        <tr>
        <td class="ui-widget-content"><input type="checkbox" class="check" name="check"></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][loc]" class="loc ui-widget-content" id="loc-<?php echo intval ($row['Loc'])?>"><?php echo $row['Loc'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][rp-code]" class="rp-code ui-widget-content" align="center" id="rp-code-<?php echo intval ($row['Rp-Code'])?>"><?php echo $row['Rp-Code'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][sku]" class="sku ui-widget-content" id="sku-<?php echo intval ($row['SKU'])?>"><?php echo $row['SKU'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][special-id]" class="special-id ui-widget-content" align="center" id="special-id-<?php echo intval ($row['Special-ID'])?>"><?php echo $row['Special-ID'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][description]" class="description ui-widget-content" id="description-<?php echo intval ($row['Description'])?>"><?php echo $row['Description'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][quantity]" class="quantity ui-widget-content" data-quantity="<?php echo $row['Quantity'] ?>" align="center" id="quantity-<?php echo intval ($row['Quantity'])?>"><?php echo $row['Quantity'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][unit]" class="unit ui-widget-content" id="unit-<?php echo intval ($row['Unit'])?>"><?php echo $row['Unit'];?></td>
        <td name="rows[0][0][quant]" style="display: none;" class="quantity_num ui-widget-content"><input type="textbox" style="width: 100px;" class="spinner" name="value" id="test"></td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

</div>

</form>
```

Index-order.php:

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['rows'])): ?>
<table cellspacing="20">
    <tr align="center">
        <th>Loc</th>
        <th>Report Code</th>
        <th>SKU</th>
        <th>Special ID</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Quantity #</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
        foreach($_POST['rows'][0] as $row): 
    ?>
        <tr align="center">
            <td><?php echo $row['loc']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['rp-code']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['sku']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['special-id']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['description']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['unit']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['quant']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php 
        endforeach; 
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to use a POST array against `<td>`'s bearing a name attribute. Maybe with JS but certainly not in pure php.

Comment: You could use hidden inputs in your table to pass values if you don't wanna go with JS.

Comment: *"I am getting no errors in my console"* - Maybe not; try error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- Yet, [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43892543/1415724) suggests that you are using JS but didn't include that in your question. Therefore this question is unclear.

Answer (score -1):

I am okay with the precedent answer, I never heard about this kind of method with PHP and it doesn't seems to be the right solution. Anyway, the following post would maybe help you : [How to get value from td's via $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288672/how-to-get-value-from-tds-via-post).

You cannot transfer datas through POST by using td ; but an alternative would be to use the "hidden" type of forms element :

`<form action="script.php" method="post">
<td class=".."><input type="hidden" name="td1" value="...">value</td>
...
</form>`

In PHP, you'll grab the data with the $_POST array and the td1 name :

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Itwould in my opinion be the easier way to get what you want in a proper way ; the link I gave upper is also talking about DOMDocument, but it looks more complex to manage with.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I said that the post would maybe help and you are right, I should have said the essential parts. Updated.